# How can I plot a vector-linear equation correctly with matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have an issue with Matlab. I'm trying to display / plot this linear equation made up by vectors but it's not working - I have tried so many different things.

With "vector-linear equation" I mean something like this (picture):

[image]

I have written the following code to do this but it's not plotting anything:

```
function VectorEq(v1, v2)
    t = linspace(-10*pi, 10*pi);
    x = v1(:,1) + t(:,1)*v2(:,1);
    y = v1(:,2) + t(:,2)*v2(:,2);
    z = v1(:,3) + t(:,3)*v2(:,3);
    plot3(x,y,z);
end
```

What am I missing here? :/

Comment: what you wrote is not what the eq says, I dont see a `v1`, unless `v1` is `[2;3;1]` also `t` is a scalar in your for loop not a vector...

Comment: t is treated as a scalar, even though you define it to be a vector of 100 elements length what is the meaning of a 1x100  length vector dot product with a 1x3 length vector?, in other words, t(:,1) is just t(1), t(:,2) is t(2) etc... you stop at t(3)..

Comment: If you just want to plot this vector you only need two points, so using `t = [-10*pi, 10*pi]` will produce the same result and save you some useless computation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the vector form of the equation of a line, `t` isn't a vector, it's the *scalar* that multiplies the direction vector. For your problem, you want to find the value of the line equation for *each of the values of* `t`

To do this, you can use Matlab's automatic broadcasting of array shapes. For example:

```
v2 = [1; 2; 3];
t = linspace(0, 1, 5);
v2 * t
```

This gives:

```
ans =

        0   0.2500   0.5000   0.7500   1.0000
        0   0.5000   1.0000   1.5000   2.0000
        0   0.7500   1.5000   2.2500   3.0000
```

Notice that the `j`th column in the answer corresponds to the `j`th element of `t`.

Such a matrix can be added to a column vector, also using broadcasting. For example:

```
v1 = [11; 12; 13];
v1 + v2 * t
```

gives

```
ans =

   11.000   11.250   11.500   11.750   12.000
   12.000   12.500   13.000   13.500   14.000
   13.000   13.750   14.500   15.250   16.000
```

The rows give you the values of your x, y, and z coordinates.

So to vectorize your problem and quickly obtain the solution:

```
function VectorEq(v1, v2)
    t = linspace(-10*pi, 10*pi);
    f = v1(:) + v2(:) * t;
    % v1(:) ensures it's a column vector
    plot3(f(1, :), f(2, :), f(3, :));
end
```

With `v1 = [1; 2; 3]` and `v2 = [0.1; 0.2; 0.3]`, we get the blue line:

[image]

The black dot and vector are the point `v1` and the unit vector of `v2`:

```
v1 = [1; 2; 3]; v2 = v1 / 10;

uv2 = v2 / norm(v2);

VectorEq(v1, v2);
hold on;
plot3(v1(1), v1(2), v1(3), '.k');
quiver3(v1(1), v1(2), v1(3), uv2(1), uv2(2), uv2(3), 'k');
```

Answer (score 4):

Here `t` is going to be a *row vector*, and doesn't have the three components you seem to assume it has. In this line parametrization `t` is a scalar, so following method should work:

```
function VectorEq(v1, v2)
    t = linspace(-10*pi, 10*pi);
    x = v1(:,1) + t*v2(:,1);
    y = v1(:,2) + t*v2(:,2);
    z = v1(:,3) + t*v2(:,3);
    plot3(x,y,z);
end
```